# ReactJs: How to properly recieve server request

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a problem with receiving server response. 
First `GET /getAllCoursesByMajor` receives the response and set the values to `courses`. But sometimes the code breaks at for loop in `GET getPreviousCourse` as it says `courses` is undefined. I understand that react is asynchronous so it does not guarantee that server response is received. How can I make sure that `courses` is loaded with server response from `getAllCoursesByMajor` and then it moves onto `getPreviousCourse` ?

```
  componentDidMount() {
        let courses;
        axios.get('/getAllCoursesByMajor',{
                  params:{
                    major : major
                  }
              }).then(function(response) {
                courses = response.data;
            });

        axios.get('/getPreviousCourse', {
              params: {
                major: major,
                name : name
              }
            }).then(function(response) {

                for(var i = 0; i < noDuplicate.length; i++){
                  for(var j = 0; j < courses.length; j++){
                    if(noDuplicate[i].courseCode === courses[j].courseCode){
                      var course = {
                        courseCode : noDuplicate[i].courseCode,
                        overview : courses[j].overview
                      }
                      self.setState({ previousCourse: self.state.previousCourse.concat([course])});
                    }
                  }

     }
```

Comment: What is the `noDuplicate` variable and why isn't the `response` from the `/getPreviousCourse` call used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens when your second request gets the response faster then your first one.`axios.get()` is async. It will not block the code execution. Your second request will start immediately after the first one and may even complete faster than it. And when that happens your variable `courses` will still be `undefined` because the response handler of your first request was not called yet to assign a value to it.

If your second request depends on the result of the first request you need to put it inside the response handler of your first request:

```js
axios.get('/getAllCoursesByMajor',{
    params: {
        major: major,
    }}).then(function(response) {
        const courses = response.data;

        axios.get('/getPreviousCourse', {
          params: {
            major: major,
            name : name
          }
        }).then(/* ... */);
    });
```

> I understand that react is asynchronous so it does not guarantee that
>   server response is received.

It has nothing to do with react doing certain things asynchronously. React doesn't know about any server requests or which library you are using to make them. The problem here is with `axios`.

It will be even better if your backend api would provide the previous course already in the first request because you are wasting a lot of time doing multiple round trips with your server when it could give your the required information in a single request.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!